# ROS gives an error "Unable to locate package ros-indigo-USARSim" while installing USARSim Package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While installing USARSim package, ros always gives an error "**Unable to locate package ros-indigo-USARSim**". i am using the following command to install USARSim Package:- **"$sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-USARSim"**.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192503/ros-gives-an-error-%22unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-usarsim%22-while-installing-usarsim-package/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2014-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think the command you tried is currently possible -- I don't find a package called `USARSim` available in the [list of the packages that are built on ROS build server in Indigo](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html).

There are [several questions](http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/tags:usarsim/page:1/) on this forum about using `USARSim` with ROS. And [this package](https://github.com/makokal/usarsim-ros) by @makokal seems a good option since some people were able to get them working together.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-09-12**:
Thank you very much for answering my question but here is one more questions: **Which package should i use to connect to USARSim through ROS-Indigo**.
**in the list of the packages that are built on ROS build server in ROS Indigo i didn't find any package which can act as ROS-USARSim interface.**

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-09-12**:
I saw you [opened another question](http://goo.gl/zUkyJy), which is a recommended way of using this type of forum. So can close this thread by clicking the check sign?